# Tracing Georeferenced image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am trying to trace in [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) after using GEO REFERENCER on the Vector menu of QGIS  to import an image . QGIS  which is amazing the [youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8Y4BjeHhlE) 
 are brilliant videos are sadly for the 2.8 version and not 3.10.1

Using the earlier version videos  I have imported the image I have and its amazing , however when creating a feature on it as a polygon using 'Add polygon ' tool box icon. I can draw around what I want but only exit this polygon creation  by clicking 'pencil' tool box item . This creates a red  outline on the map . Now if I try and edit this like my previous GEOJSON layers  I cannot and it seems locked . Am I doing something wrong as I would rather just use QGIS than create in another product.

To explain :
I have created a standard 'New Shapefile' layer and have selected this and drawn a shape into the layer using 'Add polygon' tool. It appears as a red outline  which looks great but does seem to be a feature.IF i ask the layer to count the feature it shows (0) features  The second video on youtube for QGIS 2.8 shows you how to do this addition in 2.8 not 3.10.1 . Once this is in, I expected to be able to use the 'Vertex' Tool to edit points, however when I clicked on the outline it appeared locked and did not  change to a polygon with points . I am unsure if I have missed a step as I tried to save this to GeoJson text file and the file was empty . It would possibly appear then that this is not saved into the layer as the geojson files are of 0 bytes? I must not be doing something correctly as this is an awesome package .

There must be a difference between these GEOJSON files and the layers I am now creating?

Comment: Please be more specific. Which tutorial are you following? What exactly are you trying? What tools are you using? What data type is your new layer? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: So, you have a new shapefile, you toggled `editing` (yellow pencil), toggled `add new polygon` (green blob with a yellow box with an asteriks below) and finished adding the new polygon by clicking right? Maybe you forgot the last step?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the video is incorrect on how to terminate the 'Add polygon' tool . I found a helpful answer to right **click on the map instead of clicking pencil** here: https://github.com/mtop/speciesgeocoder/wiki/Tutorial-for-creating-polygons-in-QGIS